# Execute robocopy powershell continuously between two times established

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have a program that creates temporary files in a specific folder. Then, automatically, after a few seconds, these files are deleted.

I wanted to copy those temporal files to an specific folder, I would like to use a powershell script to do this:

```
  robocopy startFolder destinationFolder *.TIFF *.JPEG *.jpg *.PNG *.GIF *.BMP *.ICO *.PBM *.PGM *.PPM /s /XO
```

My problem is that I couldn't use a scheduled task (because of the problem with limitation of seconds) or install this powershell as a Windows Service with a powershell script (as far as I know is a bad practice) . I need this powershell running all the time trying to get files at the moment that they are created, before this folders were deleted.

Could you give me a hand please? Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can implement something like DFS-R instead of a `Robocopy` solution?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it's quite what you want, but [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) does have directory monitoring funcitonality built-in.  You could add `/mon:1` which should monitor the source directory and re-run the copy when it detects one change (a new or changed file, for example).

However, a down-side of this perhaps is that using this method, robocopy won't exit - it will run until you kill it.

Edit: I've just noticed you specify in your question title that this should run between two established times, in which case you could add the `/rh:hhmm-hhmm` option to specify times between which new copies can be started.  For example, `/rh:1000-1200` should only perform the copies (and hence monitoring) between 10am and midday.

Caveat: I've not tried using the "monitor" option of robocopy, so I'm not sure what sort of delay there would be between a change taking place, and the copy being re-run, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I've tested with `/mon:1`, and doesn't work always :(. The other process maybe is too fast. It creates 59 different files, 2 pngs, but the powershell can't catch it...

Comment: I would guess that you'd have the same problem regardless - you can make any custom windows application [monitor directory changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261.aspx), but in your case you will always be in a race against the other process. Maybe you need to investigate a different approach?

Comment: Hey, your question is only 3 hours old - someone else may have the wizzo way of doing it :)